# Does SQL Server 2008 R2 offer referential integrity across databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database with user authentication information and another with business data. Is it possible to declare referential integrity constraints on columns in one database with those in another?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I just tried: `Msg 1763, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Cross-database foreign key references are not supported. Foreign key 'FOO.dbo.TEST'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.`

Comment: But cross-schema constraints should be supported, though I haven't gotten around to trying that yet.  I know they work in SS2012.

Comment: As soon as you're trying to do anything like this, you should seriously be considering consolidating the data into a single database. E.g. even if you go with a "triggers" solution as M.Ali suggests, you've got all kinds of new issues around taking consistent backups of both databases, you can't take one offline without affecting the other, etc. In other words, they're *effectively* now one database, just with lots of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referential Integrity across tables (Somewhat simple rules) is maintained with the use of Foreign Key Constraints.

More complex business rules (Cross Database Referential Integrity) is handled with Triggers.

Ideally relational data should be kept in one database yet some complex business requirement can change this, Triggers come handy in that situation.